# How to add / remove html elements and content based on the browsing device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am make a responsive web page and I want to be able to change what is showing on the page, not just through CSS but actually through Javascript (or even server side node.js ) so that redundant html is not added to every page.

**Edit**: I am interested in doing this on the client side if possible.  I will be using node for the server so any technique using that would be fine, unfortunately PHP will not help me here.

For instance, if I wanted on desktop to have:

```
 <nav>
 <ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

But on mobile devices I just wanted to have:

```
<nav>
 <select>
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
 </select>
</nav>
```

What is the best way to do this.  I would hate to write them both in the body and then just `display` one based on a media query, but I have seen that done before.

Any suggestions on how to prevent the extra content from being created would be great.

Comment: There are a number of existing scripts to do *just* that. I've had good luck with [TinyNav.js](http://tinynav.viljamis.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to send the obsolete html to the client then the server needs to know what the browser is.
The answer on how to do that is depending on the server language.

Another option is to let the client do a request for another page and load that with Ajax.

If the page has loads of differences you might want to consider to just start a subdomain for mobile ( old, non responsive way ). If your page has little difference then you might want to lazy load small parts after the main page is loaded, maybe even don't load them at all if they are down on the page.

Things to consider are that google will not index content that is not there, and everybody is using responsive design with bootstrap or zurb-foundation with easy classes to display/hide parts for different screensizes.

Comment: Is everybody who makes responsive design using bootstrap?
The thing I was thinking is that non-visual user agents and google would index the extra html (and I want to write as clean code as is possible).

Comment: Is the "everybody" offending? I see loads of responsive websites made with bootstrap or foundation. Just a personal experience. Not sure what you mean with 'clean', google does not index hidden or transparent divs for obvious reasons ( ie. text in hidden divs just there for bots ).

Comment: No I didn't mean offending, I was just curious. I was hoping that I could create html that only shows up for specific users (other than redirecting a user to a mobile specific page)

Comment: You might want to look into twig or blade, that lets you write readable server side html that can handle variables to make render decisions. I've heard of swig as well, that seems to do the same on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have multiple views, which I don't like or you could give the ul a class, for example 'desktop'. Then if a user calls the website from a mobile device, your javascript will check for all 'ul .desktop'-elements and transform it to a select element

Comment: The extra `html` would still be written in this technique correct? Also, there would need to be accompanying javascript to actually detect the desktop class somehow?

Comment: Well, if you work with jQuery for example, it is easy to detect the class. Are you familiar with it? You also don't need to write the html multiple times. You only need one html-part. You would have javascript functions doing the transformation automatically then